# Create Scatterplot in R from CSV

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following CSV document (3 columns, 1 header line, 10 data lines):

```
Artikelname,Anzahl Zeichen,Anzahl Fehler
Sport/Ski alpin,5459,42
People,2302,20
Nationale Politik,4012,43
Reportage ueber die Lebensmittelindustrie,11202,101
Wirtschaft,3192,22
Interview,2989,21
Sport/Tennis,1509,14
Filmkritik,2498,65
Regionalpolitik,3987,32
Mali-Reportage,10782,91
```

I now wish to plot the second column on the x-Axis and the third column on the y-Axis of a scatterplot in R.

```
getwd()
file <- "[filepath]"
data <- read.csv(file, skip = 1) # skip header line
data                             # print the data into the console

plot(data[2],data[3])
```

I believe it is because my data is not of the correct type yet, but I don't have any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,  remove `skip=1`.  Your current code uses the first line of data as the column names instead of data.  After reading the data correctly,  you want

```
plot(data[,2],data[,3])
```

or perhaps more simply

```
plot(data[,2:3])
```